# Question on Chapman0Kolmogorov equation

Tags: stochastic-calculus, markov-process

I am studying Chapman-Kolmogorov equation and here is the part in the chapter which I am confused about. I wonder by what theorem or condition that we can have equality of integral implies equality of the integrand.
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\alpha}\int_{-\infty}^{\beta} P_{s,x}(t,dy)P_{X_s}(dx)=\int_{-\infty}^{\alpha}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\beta} P_{u,z}(t,dy)P_{s,x}(u,dz)P_{X_s}(dx) $$
implies the equality
$$P_{s,x}(t,A)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}P_{u,z}(t,A)P_{s,x}(u,dz)$$
for all $s<u<t,x\in\mathbb{R}$, and $A\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, the Borel field of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: If $\int_{-\infty}^a f(x) \, dx = \int_{-\infty}^a g(x) \, dx$ for all $a$, then by the Fundamental theorem of calculus, taking the derivative of both sides with respect to $a$ yields $f(a) = g(a)$ for all $a$. I believe the same principle applies in your case (via the Lebesgue differentiation theorem?).